# Attempt to install Amber.js on OS X fails because grunt client not installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, amber-smalltalk

I have installed node.js and npm on my OS X box running 10.11.5. But, following the instructions at http://docs.amber-lang.net/getting-started.html, when I type:

npm install -g amber-cli

in the Terminal, I get the following result:

npm WARN amber-cli@0.100.2 requires a peer of grunt-cli@^0.1.13 but none was installed.

And the installation halts. Since this is only a warning from npm, I wonder if I really need grunt installed.

FWIW, it *does* appear I have a version of grunt in my npm directory because using locate to find it produces a billion lines, one of which is:

/Users/me/.npm/grunt

In fact, it looks like I have a bunch of grunt installs (most version 0.4.0). Which makes me reluctant to install grunt *again* since it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
npm install -g grunt-cli@0 grunt-init bower amber-cli
```

Comment: That worked! I found an obscure online reference to that solution just after I posted my question. Now I have a different problem but it's not npm-related so I'll take it elsewhere. Thanks, Chris!

Comment: Well, I guess I was wrong. I am thwarted once again. I'm tearing my (little remaining) hair out here.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, it's a problem with your path.

If nothing returns when you execute `which grunt`, it means that you need to add the location of grunt to your path.

If you installed grunt using `npm install -g`, you'll need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your path.

Since you found your grunt cli under `~/.npm`, you will need to add that to your path.

You should also add `./node_modules/bin` to your path which will cause your shell to check for npm-installed modules in the `node_modules/bin` directory in your current directory.

You can always run grunt directly, irrespective of its location, by typing: `npx grunt` using the tool included with `npm` for running npm-installed commands.

It's good practice to add all of the paths above, to catch all possible npm-installed commands.

You can update your path in the `~/.*rc` file for your shell (~/.bashrc for bash, etc.), by adding this line to the end of your rc file:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:~/.npm:./node_modules/bin:$PATH`